# Solr stops responding (or slows down to molasses)...(Solr newbie)

Tags: solrnet, solr

Running multi-core Solr under Tomcat 6.0 /Win 2008 Server and ASP.NET queries via SolrNet. One of the cores is huge i.e. ~25 million documents (~20 GB disk-space) and several fields. The other 3 cores are much smaller (few gigs each).

After a couple of queries to the large index, Solr slows down dramatically and stops responding i.e. can't even open admin console. If I restart tomcat, things again works ok for a few more queries and then molasses to stop. I have checked the machine RAM and processor usage, both are <50% utilization.

I am not sure what the issue might be - memory leak? How can I go about finding the issue?
I don't know much about Solr/Tomcat logs and which logs I should be looking at.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this degradation happen with queries only? Are there no commits involved?

Comment: I turned off all commits to isolate it. So yes happens only with qrys.

Comment: Check the Solr logs. Any warnings/errors there? Also, what are your JVM memory settings?

Comment: In the catalina log have this message java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to tune the JVM memory allocation with the -Xms and -Xmx settings. See:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#RAM_Usage_Considerations
- http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Scaling-Lucene-and-Solr#d0e245