# Solr - Faceted navigation on large index

Tags: solr, out-of-memory, faceted-search

I have an index containing 1.2 billion of documents (Solr 1.4.1). I want to enable faceted navigation on a field (int type) containg around 250 unique values.

I am getting `Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` with the default method (facet.method=fc), while the enum method is very slow (but works).

What is the best approach for a given number of documents and unique values?

**Updated:**

So if I understand correctly:

- Memory usage for faceting using fc method is: MaxDoc * 4bytes (the field type is int, 64bit JVM), so that is: 1118950216 * 4bytes = 4.1GB (aprox.)
- Memory usage for faceting using enum method is: NumberOfUniqueValues * SizeOfBitset = 250 * (1118950216 / 8) = 32GB

Is this correct?

I will try again the FC method (and give more ram to solr).

Thanks!

Comment: of which type is the field? on trunk there is another approach: facet.method=fcs (facets per segment)

Comment: @Karussell: you should make that an answer

Comment: Karussel: The field type is integer. Current I have only one segment in the (optimized) index (the index will be static). I am not sure if fcs method will help me, but I will take a look.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg44756.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to [tune the JVM memory allocation settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878502/solr-stops-responding-or-slows-down-to-molasses-solr-newbie/3878658#3878658) and/or add more memory to the server; or alternatively look into [sharding the index](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch).

Comment: I have upgraded to solr 4.0 (trunk) and added more memory to the server. It looks that is working now...